# render html file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Hello I am using expressjs. I'm trying to render files using expressjs. right now I'm using `res.sendfile()` function which is great. But now I have to separate views like header should be in a separate file footer should be in a separate file. I want to know how can I render all of this in one html file like the header, body and the foooter appear on a single page without using any templating engine just simple html file

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish and why. For example, why do you not want to use a templating engine? Try to elaborate a bit on your question, then more people will likely help you out!

Comment: @JimAho I updated the question

Comment: @JimAho the reason why I  don't want to use the templating engine is because I am new to express and the second reason is I want a clean html files no templates

Comment: @JimAho if there is some way to do it I would highly appreciate if you could tell me that

Comment: Template engine like handlebars will make your life easier as code base increases. Better learn one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't do what your asking for without a template engine.

---

Long answer:
If you want to have your HTML in different files you *must* have some functionality for composing your different files into a single file before sending it to the client. This is exactly what a templating engine can do for you.

[Here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) you can read about templating engines, and [here](http://www.hacksparrow.com/express-js-jade-partials-how-to-use-them.html) you can read about how partial pages work with the Jade engine.

In your example, the header could be one partial and the footer another partial.

Comment: A more familiar engine that works just as well for what you're doing is hogan.js. If you have trouble with Jade you can try it out. [Hogan.js](http://www.100percentjs.com/replacing-jade-with-hogan-in-an-express-js-app-the-mean-stack/)